# SQL: Displaying results in 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

I have a query that displays counts based on status column.

**This query:**

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.PDC_ID, t1.STATUS, COUNT(t1.ID) cnt 
    FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2
    WHERE  t1.dds_id = t2.id
    AND    T2.ID = 75790 and T1.PDC_ID = 2
    GROUP BY t1.PDC_ID, t2.id, t1.STATUS
```

**Returns:**

```
ID    PDC_ID   STATUS     CNT
75790   2       Active     13
75790   2       Inactive    3
```

Is there a way to display the results in one row summing counts for Active status and both statuses such as:

```
ID    PDC_ID  ACTIVE_CNT  ALL_CNT
75790   2       13         16
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Basically just fixing the `GROUP BY` and adding conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t2.id, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ACTIVE_CNT, 
       COUNT(t1.ID) ALL_CNT 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.dds_id = t2.id
WHERE T2.ID = 75790 and T1.PDC_ID = 2
GROUP BY t1.PDC_ID;
```

Note that I also fixed the `FROM` clause to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! The query is perfect if T2.ID column is the same. Let's say I have 2 ID and I still need to see 1 row.

Comment: Thanks! The query is perfect if T2.ID column is the same. Let's say I have 2 ID and I still need to see 1 row.  How can I still display 1 row (without ID, just PDC_ID, and 2 counts fields for each ID: Active and All)?

Answer (score 0):

you may use oracle over partition by analytic function 
see documentation here [partition by examples](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55)